# Capturing difference between 2 tables in one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I understand my mistake with creating questions in StackOverflow, so I want to rewrite my question.

I have two tables. One of them is my target table with old data and the source table with new data. Implicitly I want to compare these 2 tables and get information on which columns have been changed and changed status.

So I created new temporary tables as below:

```
create table #olddata (
id int,
status1 varchar(50),
status2 varchar(50),
status3 varchar(50),
)

create table #newdata (
id int,
status1 varchar(50),
status2 varchar(50),
status3 varchar(50),
)

--data inside are examples
insert into #olddata
SELECT 1 as id , 'open' as status1 ,'open' as status2, 'closed' as status3 union all
SELECT 2 as id , 'closed' as status1 ,'open' as status2, 'open' as status3 union all
SELECT 3 as id , 'open' as status1 ,'open' as status2, 'closed' as status3 

insert into #newdata
SELECT 1 as id , 'open' as status1 ,'closed' as status2, 'open' as status3 union all
SELECT 2 as id , 'closed' as status1 ,'open' as status2, 'open' as status3 union all
SELECT 3 as id , 'open' as status1 ,'open' as status2, 'open' as status3
```

I want to capture changes, where changes are called "closed" and insert getdate() in these changes. But I can't, I tried using except statement to get information on which columns have been changed:

```
--My data below shows changed
with differencescte as (
select * from #newdata
except
select * from #olddata)

--select * from differencescte

,unpivotdiff as (
select ID,Statuss,ChangedStatus
from differencescte
UNPIVOT
(
    ChangedStatus for Statuss In (status1,status2,status3)
) as up
)

select * from unpivotdiff
where ChangedStatus <> 'open'
```

My final step shows ID and status, but how to insert the date of change in except statement to get a table as below?
ID|Statuss|ChangedStatus|Dateofchanged|

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Comment: You would have to explicitely compare each column, you could do that using cross apply. I note you haven't accepted any answers to your previous questions so I'm reluctant to propose an answer here.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Is it a coincidence that `Dateofchange` is always `getdate()` or is it just a funny name for `Whenigotaroundtolookingatsomestuffandnoticeditwasdifferentidecidedtostoreaconstantstringhavingnomeaning`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one approach

```
    drop table if exists #expected
    create table #expected (
    id int,
    changedcolumn varchar(50),
    dateofchange datetime);
    
    
    with target_t as(
    SELECT 1 as id , 'open' as status1 ,'open' as status2, 'closed' as status3 union all
    SELECT 2 as id , 'closed' as status1 ,'open' as status2, 'open' as status3 union all
    SELECT 3 as id , 'open' as status1 ,'open' as status2, 'closed' as status3 )
    
    ,source_t as (
    SELECT 1 as id , 'open' as status1 ,'closed' as status2, 'open' as status3 union all
    SELECT 2 as id , 'closed' as status1 ,'open' as status2, 'open' as status3 union all
    SELECT 3 as id , 'open' as status1 ,'open' as status2, 'open' as status3 )
    
    
 INSERT INTO #expected
SELECT tb.*
FROM(
    SELECT 
        t.id
        ,'Status1' as changedcolumn
        ,getdate() AS dateofchange
    FROM target_t t
    INNER JOIN source_t s
        ON t.id = s.id
    WHERE ISNULL(t.status1,'') <> ISNULL(s.status1,'')
union all
    SELECT 
        t.id
        ,'Status2' as changedcolumn
        ,getdate() AS dateofchange
    FROM target_t t
    INNER JOIN source_t s
        ON t.id = s.id
    WHERE ISNULL(t.status2,'') <> ISNULL(s.status2,'')
union all
    SELECT 
        t.id
        ,'Status3' as changedcolumn
        ,getdate() AS dateofchange
    FROM target_t t
    INNER JOIN source_t s
        ON t.id = s.id
    WHERE ISNULL(t.status3,'') <> ISNULL(s.status3,'')
    ) tb
```

Comment: Will it work with NULL values?

Comment: Wow. It is work. Why do you use row_number?